# File input, arrays and pointers C++

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers, file-io

Im brand spanking new to programming with C and have been stumped for the past week on this program assignment (was due today). I just wanted to see if anyone could help me trouble shoot my program. I took the longest route  because I could not figure out how to read through to the 6th line of the input file and how to declare the accounts separately.

Its supposed to stimulate a banking account of 5 separate balances. Theres an interest of 35 % which is added on to original price when **U** is called, **W** is a withdrawal , **D** is a deposit, **B** is just an update of the balance.

Sample input file:

```
20000.00
10000.00
2500.00
67500.00
15000.00
2 W 200.00
4 D 50.00
1 B
2 U
3 W 125.00
0
```

And the sample output:

```
Account                             Balance
-------------------------------------------
1                               20000.00
2                               10143.00
3                                2375.00
4                               67550.00
5                               15000.00
-------------------------------------------
```

```c
int main() {
  int i, acctNumber[i];
  float acct1 = 0, acct2 = 0, acct3 = 0, acct4 = 0, acct5 = 0, service = 0;
  char transaction, buffer[10000];

  FILE* ifp = fopen("bankfile.txt", "r");
  FILE* ofp = fopen("newbankfile.txt", "w");

  if (ifp == NULL) {
    printf("Error with file\n");
  }
  while (fgets (buffer, sizeof(buffer), ifp) != NULL) {
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      fscanf(ifp, "%f%f%f%f%f", &acct1, &acct2,
             &acct3, &acct4, &acct5);
    }
    for (i = 5; i < 11; i++) {
      fscanf(ifp, "%*f%*f%*f%*f%*f%d%c%.2f", &i,
             &transaction, &service);
    }
    if (transaction == 'W') {
      acct1 = acct1 - service;
      acct2 = acct2 - service;
      acct3 = acct3 - service;
      acct4 = acct4 - service;
      acct5 = acct5 - service;
      if (transaction == 'D')
        acct1 = acct1 + service;
      acct2 = acct2 + service;
      acct3 = acct3 + service;
      acct4 = acct4 + service;
      acct5 = acct5 + service;
      if (transaction == 'U')
        acct1 = acct1 * INTEREST;
      acct2 = acct2 * INTEREST;
      acct3 = acct3 * INTEREST;
      acct4 = acct4 * INTEREST;
      acct5 = acct5 * INTEREST;
      if (transaction == 'B')
        acct1 += acct1;
      acct2 += acct2;
      acct3 += acct3;
      acct4 += acct4;
      acct5 += acct5;
    }
  }

  /* Printing to output file */
  fprintf(ofp, "Account                               Balance\n");
  fprintf(ofp, "----------------------------------------------\n");
  fprintf(ofp, "1                                       %.2f\n", acct1);
  fprintf(ofp, "2                                       %.2f\n", acct2);
  fprintf(ofp, "3                                       %.2f\n", acct3);
  fprintf(ofp, "4                                       %.2f\n", acct4);
  fprintf(ofp, "5                                       %.2f\n", acct5);

  fclose(ifp);
  fclose(ofp);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: There are so many basic errors in your program, it'll be hard to help you without re-writing the entire program. My suggestions will be to go through a C IO tutorial, such as http://www.sitepoint.com/data-input-and-output-in-c-part-1/. Hopefully that will help you correct your problems.

Comment: fscanf(ifp, "%f%f%f%f%f", &acct1, &acct2, &acct3, &acct4, &acct5); - you are reading in floats, but acct1.. etc are ints. the types need to match. same goes for your second fscanf

Comment: for(acctNumber[i] = 0; i<5; i++) - should be for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) ?

Comment: Fixing your indentation would help

Comment: Well thats my problem i understand the scanf isnt reading but i just dont know how to make it read the five seperate balances and assign them to, say account 1, account 2, so that when it reads in the 6th line that says ( 2 W 150) it knows that it needs to withdraw from account 2.

Comment: i appreciate the link, it does clear some confusion i have on reading from files but at the same time i dont know what im looking to fix so i dont know what to focus on

Comment: Is your language C or C++?  The title, the code and the tag disagree.